# UIScrollView dynamically resize UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

i have got a UILabel which is not static.

I want to resize my scroll view so that it fits the label.

Here is my idea now:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320.0, 92+self.contentLabel.frame.size.height);
```

92 stands for pixels from where my label start. (there is a heading too)

But it doesn't work, it seems to be connected with Interface Builder also.

Thanks guys.

Comment: ContentSize is in which size boundary you can scroll ... But user can see what you have set its frame

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the frame as well. The `contentSize` of the scrollview is just what is within, not the frame of the view itself. If the `contentSize` is greater than the frame it will result in scrolling.

```
CGSize buttonSize =  CGSizeMake(320.0, 92+self.contentLabel.frame.size.height);
self.scrollView.contentSize = buttonSize;
self.scrollView.frame = CGSizeMake(0, 0, 320.0, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height);
```