# table view with both horizontal and vertical scrolling in iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to create a table view with both horizontal and vertical scrolling. The content in each row will be label with text. The horizontal scrolling should there when the label size increases the width of the table view. (ie, I dont want to show label's text like "abcdefg...") Is it possible?

Comment: u can do it using scroll view ! add scr0ll view and then add your table view asa subView to your scroll view !!

Comment: you should use GridView for vertical & Horizontal scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `UIScrollView` contentSize property through code and make sure that `UIScrollView` contentSize property will have the same height but it would have a greater width than tableView.

OR

You can use an `UIScrollView` and then inside add the `UITableView`. This `UIScrollView` will have the same size that your `UITableView` have now, but the `UIScrollView` contentSize property will have the same height but it would have a greater width.

Comment: Yeah, now i added my tableview inside the scrollView. But i want to set this scrollview content size dynamically according to the label size inside the row in the tableview. How can I do this?

Comment: Checkout this link :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902223/uiscrollview-dynamically-resize-uilabel

Comment: Also this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470653/monotouch-uiscrollview-not-scrolling-with-dyanmic-uilabel-height

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `UIScrollView` and then inside add the `UITableView`. This `UIScrollView` will have the same size that your `UITableView` have now, but the `UIScrollView` contentSize property will have the same height but it would have a greater width.

see [UITableView scroll both vertically and horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156573/uitableview-scroll-both-vertically-and-horizontally/9156646#9156646)

and  https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView

Answer (score 0):

use the following may it work for u.....

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||   interfaceOrientation== UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

also make changes in inteface builder to adjust size and width